# AFNetworking NSData - Incompatible block pointer types sending

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsdata

I am trying to redo some code to use AFNetworking. I have this method below:

```
-(NSArray *)GetTableDataOfPhase:(NSString *)phase
{
    NSString *phaseRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?jobNo=%@",kIP,phase];
    NSURL *JSONURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phaseRequestString];
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:JSONURL];
            NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
        if(data == nil)
            return nil;
        NSError *myError;
        NSArray *tableArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&myError]];



    return tableArray;
}
```

and right now I am trying to alter it so it still returns an array, I have tried doing this:

```
-(NSArray *)GetTableDataOfPhase:(NSString *)phase
{
    NSString *phaseRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?jobNo=%@",kIP,phase];
    NSURL *JSONURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phaseRequestString];
    NSURLResponse* response = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:JSONURL];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:responseObject returningResponse:&response error:nil];
        if(data == nil)
            return nil;
        NSError *myError;
        NSArray *tableArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&myError]];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {


    }];

    [operation start];


    return tableArray;
}
```

but I got this error:

```
/Users/jamessuske/Documents/My Programs/SSiPad(Device Only)ios7/SchedulingiPadApplication/Classes/LHJSonData.m:168:46: Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void *(^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *, id)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *, id)'
```

and this warning:

```
/Users/jamessuske/Documents/My Programs/SSiPad(Device Only)ios7/SchedulingiPadApplication/Classes/LHJSonData.m:170:97: Sending 'NSURLResponse *const *' to parameter of type 'NSURLResponse **' discards qualifiers
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
- (void)GetRequest
{
    //refresh table view
    [dataSource.editedCellHolder removeAllObjects];
    [dataSource.cellHolder removeAllObjects];
    [dataSource.cellHolderDisplay removeAllObjects];


    NSArray *tableData = [dataSource.areaData GetTableDataOfPhase:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",areaPickerSelectionString,unitPickerSelectionString]];

    if(tableData == nil)
        [self CustomAlert:@"Data was not recieved from the server, please check internet/VPN settings, Or contact Software Vendor for assistance."];
    [dataSource PopulateTableData:tableData];
    [indicatorView stopAnimating];
    [indicatorView removeFromSuperview];
    [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
    loadingView = nil;
    indicatorView =nil;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2f target:self selector:@selector(DisplayTable) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Using AFNetworking, you should entirely lose the `NSURLConnection` request.
2. Likewise, the default `responseSerializer` does the JSON parsing for you, so you can lose the `NSJSONSerialization` parsing. AFNetworking does all of that for you.
3. Likewise, don't build URL parameters manually, but rather again let AFNetworking do that for you. By default, AFNetworking uses a `requestSerializer` that will build the request for you.
4. Your old method ran synchronously, which is generally a bad idea. Instead, you should use asynchronous patterns (e.g. a `completionHandler` block).

So, pulling all of this together, it probably looks like:

```
- (void)getTableDataOfPhase:(NSString *)phase completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *resultsObject, NSError *error))completionHandler
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"jobNo" : phase};

    [manager GET:kIP parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        completionHandler(responseObject, nil);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        completionHandler(nil, error);
    }];
}
```

And you'd call it like so:

```
[self getTableDataOfPhase:@"..." completionHandler:^(NSArray *resultsObject, NSError *error) {
    if (resultsObject) {
        // use NSArray here
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
    }
}];

// but don't try to use the `resultsObject` array here!
```

Comment: this is how I would call it from another file...would this still work? I get no errors. I have updated my question with how I am calling it

Comment: Yes, it would still work, though obviously you would put the code that should be performed after the data is retrieved inside the `completionHandler` block, not after it.